# The speed of light/EM waves in vacuum; as if there was another one in non-vacuum?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, refraction

Q1: is there a speed of a photon other than in "vacuum"?

Q2: isn't "speed of light in vacuum" misleading?

If I understand, that light moves with speed of light until there is "something in between" (no matter what) (1)

What I ask for, is not a deeply explanation; it's just:

Children ask me:

- "But how can be light slower" if it is a constant?

My explaination is:

- "Till it collides" (not the deepest answer, I know)

The question (since I prob. are not at the pulls of new physics): **Is there another speed of light  than in "vacuum"  / nothing crossing ?**

(1) no discusss, what "what" is

Comment: Google for "index of refraction".

Comment: @dmckee: refraction index,was not my question; you will agree, that a photon wont change impulse on self behalf, so there is "what" in between. and (1) no diskuss what "what" is

Comment: The photon picture of how light moved in a medium is a *hard* problem that involves diffractive forward scattering. I strongly suggest that you learn the classical wave picture first: the result is the same and the mechanism is almost the same but the "why" of the mechanism is much more intuitive.

Comment: That something "in between" is called matter and there are no photons in matter, only quasi-particles of photons that are coupled to atoms and electrons. It's the quasi-particle velocity that we measure when we measure light propagation in diffractive materials, and even that is greatly complicated by the difference between phase and group velocities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed of light is constant.

But in some substances , still transparent , light is absorbed and retransmitted ( with the same properties ) , spending some time. With not well transparent material, things are more complex. Anyway, between 2 obstacles, it's the vacuum and the speed remains constant and maximum.

How many are retransmitted and the specific speed depend on the light frequency ( dispersion , see the [prism image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Dispersion) ) , the [transparency and translucency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency) of the substance and its [refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index).

Comment: if light is coherently propagated through media transparent at that wavelength, then there is no absorption at that wavelength.  Instead what happens is a form of scattering called forward coherent scattering.

Answer (score 5):

Light is described well by the classical electromagnetic theory and [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations).
In this framework, the classical one, the speed of light is constant in vacuum. When light impinges on transparent materials, its speed, classically changes, and this is measured with the index of refraction of the material:

[image: index of refraction]

where c is the velocity of light in vacuum and v its velocity in the transparent medium. This can be measured with [various methods](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/prism.html) and thus the speed of light in the material is a measurable quantity.

The classical electrodynamics framework emerges from an underlying quantum mechanics framework. In this framework electromagnetic waves emerge as a confluence of innumerable photons, to which the speed of light in vacuum is assigned.

As the dimensions of quantum mechanical interactions is very small, the photon moves in vacuum until it interacts with a field from the molecules. For transparent materials the probability of the photon scattering elastically is very large in the direction that creates the macroscopically observed index of refraction. In a sense a photon impinging on a crystal is the quantum mechanical boundary problem "photon + crystal" and the solution comes out that the over all speed within the crystal changes due to this interaction.

Answer (score -1):

first the speed of light is related to the permittivity and permeability of the medium. changing either one of those values changes the speed of light.

copper has different values then free space. the speed of light through copper is 2/3rds that of free space. about 1 foot per nanosecond. slightly faster in aluminum, slower in iron. this can be measured with an oscilloscope.

freespace is not perfectly even. there are variants.

these are simple facts that can be imperially verified and are the basis of electromagnetic communication. it is a provable fact that free space has an inductive reactance of 376 ohms. and that should start you thinking ... how can something that is devoid of all things have a measurable property.

Comment: Length is a measurable property. Are you saying a complete vacuum can't have a length or volume? There is nothing wrong with a vacuum having measurable properties. Also, posting the same answer on multiple questions is frowned upon. If both questions can be answered identically, then close one as a duplicate of the other. Otherwise, at least one of your posts is not an answer to the posted question

Comment: I am speaking of a measurable property of 'nothing', that is free space, a vacuum, has an inductive reactance of 376 ohms. the implication is that a space vacuum is not completely devoid of 'stuff' and that the definition of nothing is that it has no properties. my answer is applicable to both questions one which is a vague question about the speed of light in a vacuum, that some have used as a springboard to a near paranoid screed and this, a clear question about the speed of light in various mediums and why. this should be perfectly clear, it is simple electrodynamics. tia for the -

Comment: sorry for wasting electrons , by duplicating answers.

Comment: The definition of a pure vacuum is that it is devoid of matter, not that it is absent of any properties.

Comment: then it is not 'empty' if it has properties

Comment: You are missing the point. A pure vacuum is *defined* as a region of space void of matter. It can still have properties while meeting that criterion. Twisting words by saying "if it has properties, it's not empty" is irrelevant. It is a vacuum and it has measurable properties. Regions that meet the requirements to be called vacuums often do have measurable properties. Thus, if you have problems with that idea, your issue is more with the definition of the term "vacuum" than it is with anything else. But since the definition is what it is, you'll just have to accept it.

Comment: emptiness for a vacuum does not mean "void of everything". That is an invalid interpretation. If it meant that, then vacuums would not exist because they would need to be void of spacetime as well.